# bzr merge - reviewing another branches commit notes ('merge tips') before committing

Tags: version-control, merge, controls, version, bazaar

I have a developer who has made some changes, and has asked that I merge them in.  In order to be safe, I haven't merged/committed his work outright, but instead made a copy of his branch so that I can do a 'bzr log --forward -n 0 -v | less' to see his commit notes, and to understand the files which were modified/added.

Since he has made several changes, I don't want to merge them all in one shot.  Instead, I'd like to commit his changes to my branch one at a time after reviewing them.

Problem is, I don't see any revision IDs for each of the "merge tips" for his changes.

If for example, he's committed changes at r250, 251, 252, and I merge all these changes in to the working tree, how can commit his r250?  Do I have to merge his changes in one at a time? or is there a way of doing this via the "merge tips"?

I'm not sure how useful merge tips are, if they only show you comments, and don't provide an ability to merge each tip in individually.

Of course I may be missing something which is common knowledge; if so, please enlighten me.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of working *against* merge, work *with* it.  Merge is designed to pull multiple changes at once like this, while still maintaining the separate underlying commits.  Check out his branch, and review each one of his commits, one at a time.  Once you are satisfied with them all, merge the whole set in one go.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.  Stepping back / bigger picture, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd merge someone else's changes into my working folder, then

> bzr qlog

and see what each change was, then from

> bzr qcommit

you can revert the files you don't want to include... and commit the rest.

I'm fairly new to bazaar though. :)